# Matrix equation using Choleski decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, bayesian

I want to understand the answer to the following matrix equation but lack some knowledge of the linear algebra:

$(\beta-b)'B^{-1}(\beta-b)=(B^{\frac{-1}{2}}b-B^{\frac{-1}{2}}\beta)'(B^{\frac{-1}{2}}b-B^{\frac{-1}{2}}\beta)$

I am supposed to arrive with the result on RHS using Choleski decomposition which yields $B^{-1}=B^{\frac{-1}{2}'}B^{\frac{-1}{2}}$. The thing that really bugs me is the reversed order of $b$ and $\beta$ .

The above problem arises when I want to derive the marginals for the following posterior density: 
\begin{equation}
p(\beta,\sigma^2|y) \propto \sigma^{-k} \exp\Bigg(\frac{-(\beta-b)'B^{-1}(\beta-b)}{2\sigma^2}\Bigg) \Bigg(\frac{1}{\sigma}\Bigg)^{N+2} \exp \Bigg(\frac{-(y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)}{2\sigma^2}\Bigg)
\end{equation}

that I obtained from assuming the natural conjugate prior for $\beta$ given $\sigma^2$:
\begin{equation}
p(\beta|\sigma^2) \propto |\sigma^2B|^{-1/2} \exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2}(\beta-b)'B^{-1}(\beta-b) \Big)
\end{equation}

where $B$ and $\beta$ are prior parameters.

For $\sigma^2$ an uninformative prior is assumed:
\begin{equation}
p(\sigma^2) \propto \sigma^{-2}
\end{equation}

---

Moreover can anyone recommend some resources (sites, textbooks) that allow one to practice such equations? I am quite comfortable with general matrix operations but struggle in equations like the one presented above.

Comment: You should specify more; what exactly are $b$, $B$ and $\beta$?

Answer (score 1):

$(Q^\frac12x)^T(Q^\frac12x) = x^T{Q^\frac12}^TQ^\frac12x = x^TQx$  always (when $Q$ has a Cholesky factor). And it is the same as $(-x)^TQ(-x)$ if that's what worries you.